# difference between Prototype constructor and private property

Tags: javascript, html

Consider the first scenario:

```
function f(){
       console.log("inside the function : " + f.myVar);
}
f.prototype.myVar = 1;
var myObject = new f();
console.log("from the object : " + myObject.myVar);
```

And this is the output:

```
inside the function : undefined
from the object : 1
```

Question: why myVar isn't available in function? If it is stored in the objects prototype it is supposed to be accessible in f().

Now this scenario:

```
function f(){
       console.log("inside the function : " + this.myVar);
}
f.prototype.myVar = 1;
var myObject = new f();
console.log("from the object : " + myObject.myVar);
```

And the output:

```
inside the function : 1
from the object : 1
```

Question: Why I'm getting different result? if 'this' refers to the object doesn't f.myVar mean access myVar in myObject ?

And now this scenario:

```
function f(){
       console.log("inside the function : " + f.myVar);
       console.log("inside the function using 'this' : " + this.myVar);
}
f.myVar = 1;
var myObject = new f();
console.log("from the  object : " + myObject.myVar);
```

output:

```
inside the function : 1
inside the function using 'this' : undefined
from the object : undefined
```

So if I set a property without using prototype it should'nt be available in instantiated objects. But if I write the script like this, it'll deliver a strange result:

```
function f(){
       console.log("inside the function : " + f.myVar);
}
f.myVar = 1;
var myObject = new f();
console.log("from the first object : " + myObject.myVar);
var strangeObject = myObject.constructor;
console.log("from the strange object : " + strangeObject.myVar);
```

Output:

```
inside the function : 1
from the first object : undefined
from the strange object : 1
```

Where does that "f.myVar" store? Whose variable is that? I'm confused what is the difference between all scenarios above. A complete carification would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

**The main problem is that I don't know what this exactly mean:**

```
function f(){}
f.someVar = someValue;
```

**Because in other languages function is an abstract concept and in fact doesn't exist until it is called. Now in JS it is said that functions are objects by default. Ok so I should have an object like this by the script above:**

```
{someVar : sameValue}
```

***in fact I think this should be as same as:***

```
function f(){this.someVar = someValue;} //should create {someVar : someValue}
```

**If this is the case EVERY object instantiated by calling "new f()" must contain this "someVar" but they don't.**

Comment: Old question, welcome to OOP in JS. But you are so lucky that you could adopt ES6 class now :D

Comment: as for _strange_ result, really `constructor` property is reference to constructor, so `myObject.constructor` is same as `f`

Comment: for edit: `function f(){}
f.someVar = someValue;` this analog _static_ function or property, that can be called without instance

Comment: @Grundy why isn't this thing you call static function accessible from instances? And what is it's structure in memory (Code Level). If that's an object, how is the object formed? If I I don't know these, I can't understand the situation well

Comment: @CS, first and main, when you do `new f()` to created object just setup prototype `f.prototype`, and if in code you add `someVar` property not to `f.prototype` but simple `f` this property not added to created object.

Comment: @Grundy Yes I see it doesn't. But my question is why not?!

Comment: because properties that added directly to function object, not used when we create object and use this function as constructor, in this case used just properties from proptotype

Comment: @Grundy By saying "why" I mean technically why. I mean what happens that the interpreter exclude f.myVar from being inherited? There must be implementation differences between where to store function properties (which are inherited) and between 'place' and 'type' of private ones (or more exactly function specific ones)

Comment: so, as i say: `f.myVar` saved in function object, and function that used in inheritance have two type: first saved in `f.prototype` second created when `f` called as constructor like `new f()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why myVar isn't available in function? If it is stored in the objects
>   prototype it is supposed to be accessible in f().

It's accessible in the function, but not as `f.myVar`, but as `this.myVar` or `f.prototype.myVar`.

> Why I'm getting different result? if 'this' refers to the object
>   doesn't f.myVar mean access myVar in myObject ?

The function `f` is not the same as the object instance. The function is the constructor for the object, and using it with the `new` keyword creates an instance that is a separate object from the function.

When you use `f.var`, that is the property `var` of the function object. When you use `this.var` in the function, that is the property `var` in the object instance that the use of the `new` keyword created.

If you use `f.var`, that is a property of the constructor function object, so it will be the same variable even if you create multiple instances of the object, and it's only accessible using `f.var`.

If you use `f.prototype.var`, that will also be a variable that is the same for all instances of the object, but that can also be accessed using `this.var` as the object inherits the members of the prototype.

Example:

```
function f() {
  console.log(f.var); // shows "42"
  console.log(f.prototype.var); // shows "0.01"
  console.log(this.var); shows "0.01";
}

f.var = 42;
f.prototype.var = 0.01;
```

If you want a variable that is local to each instance of the object, you should use neither of those. You should assign a value to `this.var`, which will make it a property in the object instance.

Example:

```
function f(value) {
    this.var = value;
}

f.prototype.getValue = function(){
  return this.var;
};

var instance1 = new f(42);
var instance2 = new f(0.01);

// now you have two instances with separate values:

console.log(instance1.getValue()); // shows "42"
console.log(instance2.getValue()); // shows "0.01"
```

Comment: I nearly already known what you said but unfortunately didn't get what I wanted. My question is "where" does "f.var" belong to? if it is "inside" function object, that should be inherited to other instances.

Comment: @CS.: The `f.var` is a property of the object `f` (as functions in JavaScript is also objects), but it's not inside the function. You can think of it as something that you hang on the outside of the function. The code inside the function can reach out and access `f.var`, just as any code outside the function can access `f.var`.

Comment: So what happens to the "strangeObject"? Did you notice that?

Comment: @CS.: `strangeObject` is the same as `f`, as the constructor is the function that you used to create the object. Using `strangeObject.var` is the same as using `f.var`.

Comment: Now I love C language more than before. Because I always want to know what happens behind the scene not just 'consider' to be 'something'. So if we want to express it in C way can we say function is a pointer to a data structure as well as strangeObject and they point to the same location?

Comment: @CS.: Yes, references to objects (including functions) works similar to pointers in C. Both `f` and `strangeObject` are references to the same object of the type `Function`.

Comment: if I say  : "f = poiter to new object as {var1 : val1, var2: val2 , ..... , function_body{OUR CODE}, ..... }" And  strangeObject = f (Also Pointer).. is this consideration correct? So I can say function is an object with key-pair values and a special key-pair as function body which is executed when we call "new f()" and returns the address of this new object? So this way the border between function object's properties and function instants' properties is clear.

Comment: @CS.: Yes, but note that the object instance created by `new f()` is separate from the function object that `f` is pointing to. The new object will inherit `f.prototype`, but nothing else from the `f` object. Adding properties to the `f` object has nothing to do with using it as a constructor.

Comment: Yes I mentioned that "new f()" returns address to the new object

Comment: @CS.: Yes, I just wanted to clarify that they are separate objects, and that the function object itself isn't used as a blueprint for the created object. :)

Answer (score 2):

Start out by examining the definition of the word *prototype*. I think it's important to keep this in mind when thinking about how new objects are created in JavaScript.

**pro·to·type**

*noun*

1. a first, typical or preliminary model of something, especially a machine, from which other forms are developed or copied.

*verb*

1. make a prototype of (a product).

---

A prototype is a model from which another form will be copied.

When you create a new object in JavaScript, that is exactly what happens.

```
var obj = new MyObject();
```

In the above code, there are many things that happen, but in the context of the question, there are two things that happen which are relevant:

1. The prototype is applied to a new object.
2. The function MyObject is called, with `this` set to the new object.

With this knowledge in mind, let's take a look at the different forms of setting variables you have described:

```
function MyObject() {}
MyObject.myProperty = 'MyProperty';
```

It's important to understand that functions themselves are objects in JavaScript. Therefore, `function MyObject` is an object instance to itself. On the second line, we have set the property `myProperty` on this function object.

Refer back to the steps of creation above, and you will notice that it does not include applying properties from the function object to the new instance object. It only applies properties from the function object's prototype, and then runs the body of the function with `this` set to the new instance.

```
function MyObject() {
    this.myProperty = 'MyProperty';
}
```

Here, the property `myProperty` is set on the individual instance.

```
function MyObject() {}
MyObject.prototype.myProperty = 'MyProperty';
```

In this example, each new instance of `MyObject` will be given its own property called `myProperty` and the value set to `'MyProperty'`. From there, each instance can change its own `myProperty` to whatever value it needs without affecting the other.

```
function MyObject() {
    console.log('myProperty', this.myProperty); //Will output 'Outside constructor.'
    this.myProperty = 'Inside constructor.';
    console.log('myProperty', this.myProperty); //Will output 'Inside constructor.
}

MyObject.prototype.myProperty = 'Outside constructor.';
```

The above example shows how `myProperty` is first applied from the prototype, then overwritten by the value applies in the function that is run.

---

Let's take a look at an example with all the forms you mentioned:

```js
var output1 = document.getElementById('output1'),
    output2 = document.getElementById('output2'),
    output3 = document.getElementById('output3');

function MyObject(myProperty) {
  this.myProperty = myProperty;
}

MyObject.myProperty = 'Function property.';

MyObject.prototype.myProperty = 'Prototype property.';


var obj = new MyObject('Constructor property');

output1.innerHTML = obj.myProperty;
output2.innerHTML = MyObject.myProperty;
output3.innerHTML = MyObject.prototype.myProperty;
```

```html
<div id="output1"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
<div id="output3"></div>
```

---

In the above example, you'll see how each can be referenced. Now examine it a little closer. Take a look at what happens with your 'Function property' when it is set from two different object instances:

```js
var output1 = document.getElementById('output1'),
    output2 = document.getElementById('output2');


function MyObject() {
  //We are concatenating a string to the end of the property on each function call.
  MyObject.myProperty += ' test ';
}

MyObject.myProperty = 'Function property.';


var obj1 = new MyObject();
var obj2 = new MyObject();

output1.innerHTML = MyObject.myProperty;
output2.innerHTML = MyObject.myProperty;
```

```html
<div id="output1"></div>
<div id="output2"></div>
```

The above code demonstrates how the function level property is effectively shared. That's because it's not part of each instance. It's part of the function object.

---

Here I'll show you the process that takes place with the `new` operator, without actually using the `new` operator:

```js
var output = document.getElementById('output');


//Let's have an object that has a prototype property with some properties:
var MyPrototypeObject = {
  prototype: {
    myPrototypeProperty: 'Prototype property'
  }
};

//Let's specify a function that will be used as a constructor:
function MyConstructorFunction() {
  this.myInstanceProperty = 'Instance property';
}


//First, new creates an object
var obj = {};

//Next, it applies all the properties from the prototype. We are using the MyPrototypeObject's prototype property for this example
for (var key in MyPrototypeObject.prototype) {
  var val = MyPrototypeObject.prototype[key];
  
  //Set the same property on the new object.
  obj[key] = val;
}

//Now the prototype has been applied, let's apply the constructor function that was called.
MyConstructorFunction.call(obj); //This calls MyConstructorFunction with this set to obj.

output.innerHTML = 'myPrototypeProperty: ' + obj.myPrototypeProperty + '<br>' + 'myInstanceProperty: ' + obj.myInstanceProperty;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I still don't know where someVar is stored and as what? If it becomes part of function 'object' so when we instantiate a new object, the new object should have all the function's properties like 'someVar'. Please read last part of my edit.

Comment: @CS. I've tried to rewrite the answer to be more clear. Can you take another look and see if this clears up your question?

Comment: Yes, thank you, the problem is already solved as others helped too. I upvote your good answer but accept guffa's

Answer (score 0):

As for question in edit, really all simple :-)

you have a function object `function f(){}`

you add to this object property, like you can add property to any other object in javascript `f.someVar = 1`

this not same as `function f(){this.someVar = someValue;}` because `this` in javascript depends on how function calling and can refers to created object, global object, or something else if called with `call` or `apply` function.

When you create object with `new` operator - you call `f` as constructor, and in this case `this` inside function referes to created object, and all properties added inside function as `this.something = val` add to created object.

**Note:** that you not use any property from function directly, so this not added to created object.

As for `prototype`: when you create object - you just set `prototype` property of created object to `f.prototype` object. So at end when you create object, you not use any property directly added to function object, just property from prototype and property that added manually to `this` in constructor

Comment: Ok you say function is just as an object and we can add properties to it. But a part of this object will be instantiated by using new. can we say function have some properties (including what we add like 'f.myVar') and a "Code" part (function body that we write) which is executed and create a new object when using 'new' keyword? And this 'code' part doesn't have to do with other properties that we add?

Comment: @CS. why not? inside function body you also can use something like `function f(){ this.myFromGlobal = f.global;}`. Or you mean something else?

Comment: I mean function OBJECT is something like this: {var1 : val1, var2 : val2 ,..... , function_body : {OUR CODE} , ......} and only function_body is related to "instantiated objects". other properties (those we add) are specifically related to function object itself.

Comment: almost, really structure a bit difference, but i think this generally true, when you instantiate object, you just call `function_body` and pass created object to you `function_body` as `this`

Comment: I wish there were official documents to explain the structure but that is most probably like what I said and if true so the difference is clear and there would be no question why f.myVar is not instantiated. Thanks my friend.

Comment: @CS., i think you can see [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are getting confused with the prototype of function and object.

Here's a quote from the book [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html) explaining the difference:

> It is important to note the distinction between the way a prototype is
>   associated with a constructor (through its prototype property) and the
>   way objects have a prototype (which can be retrieved with
>   Object.getPrototypeOf). The actual prototype of a constructor is
>   Function.prototype since constructors are functions. Its prototype
>   property will be the prototype of instances created through it but is
>   not its own prototype.

Comment: if I say : "f =  {var1 : val1, var2: val2 , ..... , function_body{OUR CODE}, ..... }" do you think  this consideration is correct? So I can say function is an object with key-pair values and a special key-pair as function body which is executed when we call "new f()" and returns the address of this new object? So this way the border between function object's properties and function instants' properties is clear.